# Checkbutton with more than two states in Python (checked, unchecked and something between)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a Checkbutton (tkinter) in Python with more than two states.
I have searched the internet but have not found anything. (perhaps I have not searched enough)
Can somebody help me -> thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. You need to provide some code so we can see what you have done so far and we will be able to help. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The Checkbutton documentation covers the third state. There is the option `tristatevalue` which can be used to show the third state (on, off, tristate). There is also the option `tristateimage` if you are defining custom images for your checkbuttons.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.StringVar(value="on")
var2 = tk.StringVar(value="off")
var3 = tk.StringVar(value="tristate")
cb1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="On", onvalue="on", offvalue="off", tristatevalue="tristate", variable=var1)
cb2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Off", onvalue="on", offvalue="off", tristatevalue="tristate", variable=var2)
cb3 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="tristate", onvalue="on", offvalue="off", tristatevalue="tristate", variable=var3)

cb1.pack(anchor="w")
cb2.pack(anchor="w")
cb3.pack(anchor="w")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of three states]

If you want the user to be able to toggle between the three values, add the following code. Note that this function has hard-coded strings for the three values so you might have to modify it for your own code. Also, I don't know what order you want the values to switch between so in this example the tristate value comes after the "off" value (eg: "on" -> "off" -> "tristate").

```
def toggle_checkbutton(event):
    checkbutton = event.widget
    varname = checkbutton.cget("variable")
    current_value = checkbutton.getvar(varname)
    if current_value == "on":
        new_value = "off"
    elif current_value == "off":
        new_value = "tristate"
    else:
        new_value = "on"
    checkbutton.setvar(varname, new_value)
    return "break"

cb1.bind("<1>", toggle_checkbutton)
cb2.bind("<1>", toggle_checkbutton)
cb3.bind("<1>", toggle_checkbutton)
```

Comment: It works only once.
As soon as I click several times, the third state is no longer present.
Do you know what the reason is.

Comment: @Bleron: yes, by default a button click toggles between the on and off state. If you want to be able to toggle between all three you'll have to create a special binding to do that. Normally this third state is set programmatically when you select or unselect checkboxes that are children in a hierarchy of checkboxes.

Comment: Could you please make a example. :)

Comment: @Bleron: I've updated the example.